# Selecting several elements from a grid using while loop and xpath in Selenium webDriver

Tags: xpath, while-loop, selenium-webdriver

I have a while loop containing an Xpath expression. How can I have the while loop working properly with only the value of tr[index] changing within the Xpath? Below is an example:

```
//this is what I currently have:
while(webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sharing_list']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]")).isDisplayed())
   {
       webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sharing_list']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/span")).click();

   }

//and this is what I would like to have:

    int n=1;

while(webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sharing_list']/tbody/tr[n]/td[4]")).isDisplayed())
   {
       webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sharing_list']/tbody/tr[n]/td[4]/span")).click();
       n++;

   }
```

Does any one have an idea how to make it work? I am using Selenium 2.33.
Your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a String issue.  Replace your `tr[n]` with `tr["+n+"]`

Comment: Can you explain that syntax?  What do the '+' symbols do, being wrapped around the 'n'?

Comment: The full string is this: `"//*[@id='sharing_list']/tbody/tr["+n+"]/td[4]"`  I'm ending the String, and appending the variable